# Using mysql query fetch data If Col1 contains any substring of input text

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

I need your help regarding making mysql query. I want to fetch data if specific col contains any substring or multiple substring or whole text.

Eg:

```
input : love you.
```

result from column:

```
1: I love myself.
2: you are my life.
3. someone said you must do love in life once.
4. he said you are bad.
5. my parents said me love you.
```

Here data has been fetched in example from colunm which contains subtring of input.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Split your input string on a white-space and add each element to your WHERE clause with `LIKE '%s%'` (where s is your substring)... simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular `SELECT` with `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table'
WHERE 'column' LIKE '%love%'
OR 'column' LIKE '%you%';
```

Comment: thanks for giving attention to this. but i want dynamically. Means input can contains any no of words/substrings. So based on given input it fetch data. if you got it please give solution. i am very thankful to you.